# Get current user in FormsAuthentification

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the code that i use in login function :

> FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Model.IDUser, false);

I'm wondring how can i read "IDuser"(current user connected) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the current user by doing

```
var current = Membership.GetUser();
```

It does a bit more than just returning the current user, as in it updates the database the LastActivity column in the data store
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx